# In pure functional languages, is there an algorithm to get the inverse function?

Tags: functional-programming

In pure functional languages like Haskell, is there an algorithm to get the inverse of a function, (edit) when it is bijective? And is there a specific way to program your function so it is?

Comment: Mathematically it is not wrong to say that, in the case of `f x = 1`, the inverse of 1 is a set of integers and the inverse of anything else is an empty set. Regardless of what some answers say, the function not being bijective is not the biggest problem.

Comment: The correct response is YES, but it's not efficient. Let f : A -> B and A finite, then, given b€B, you "only" must to inspect all f(A) to find all a€A that f(a)=b. In a quantum computer, perhaps would have O(size(a)) complexity. Of course, you look for a practical algorithm. It is not (has O(2^size(a)) ), but exists...

Comment: QuickCheck is doing it exactly (they look for a False in f : A -> Bool).

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: I disagree; that's not usually what is meant by inverse. Pretty much every time I encounter the term, the inverse of `f` is a function `g` such that `f . g = id` and `g . f = id`. Your candidate doesn't even typecheck in that case.

Comment: @BenMillwood, you're right. What I said is called an inverse image, not an inverse function. My point was that the answers pointing out that `f x = 1` has no inverse take a very narrow approach and ignore the whole complexity of the problem.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė "having an inverse" is exactly the same as saying the inverse image is a singleton.

Comment: @josejuan: It's a common misconception that quantum computers can perform operations on exponentially-many copies of data in parallel. Remember, measurement is destructive, and measuring an entangled value produces only one classical value. [Holevo's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holevo's_theorem) says that *n* qubits can encode at most *n* bits. And [it would be considered very surprising](http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec10.html) if quantum computers could efficiently solve all NP problems (more formally, we think that NP ⊄ [BQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQP)). [cont…]

Comment: @josejuan: […cont] For the specific case you mention—searching through an unordered list of elements—you want to use [Grover's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm), which searches a length-*n* list in O(√*n*) time on a quantum computer.  And actually, Wikipedia says that "it may be more accurate to describe [Grover's algorithm] as 'inverting a function,'" so there you go.  So that gives a quadratic speedup: instead of O(2^|A|) time to invert a function, you end up with O(2^(|A|/2)) time, and can do no better.

Comment: Thank you @AntalS-Z, I said "perhaps would have" because "The relation between BQP and NP is not known"

Answer (score 105, accepted):

In some cases, yes! There's a beautiful paper called [Bidirectionalization for Free!](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.143.3248&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which discusses a few cases -- when your function is sufficiently polymorphic -- where it is possible, completely automatically to derive an inverse function. (It also discusses what makes the problem hard when the functions are not polymorphic.)

What you get out in the case your function is invertible is the inverse (with a spurious input); in other cases, you get a function which tries to "merge" an old input value and a new output value.

Comment: Here's a more recent paper that surveys the state of the art in bidirectionalization. It includes three families of techniques, including "syntactic" and combinator based approaches as well: http://www.iai.uni-bonn.de/~jv/ssgip-bidirectional-final.pdf

Comment: And just to mention, in 2008 there was this message to -cafe, with an evil hack for inverting `put` functions into any record structures deriving `Data`: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2008-April/042193.html using an approach similar to that later presented (more rigorously, more generally, more principled, etc.) in "for free".

Comment: It is 2017 and of course the link to the paper is not valid anymore here is the updated one:https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5f0d/ef02dbd96e102be9104d2ceb728d2a2a5beb.pdf

Answer (score 38):

No, it's not possible in general.

Proof: consider bijective functions of type

```
type F = [Bit] -> [Bit]
```

with

```
data Bit = B0 | B1
```

Assume we have an inverter `inv :: F -> F` such that `inv f . f ≡ id`. Say we have tested it for the function `f = id`, by confirming that

```
inv f (repeat B0) -> (B0 : ls)
```

Since this first `B0` in the output must have come after some finite time, we have an upper bound `n` on both the depth to which `inv` had actually evaluated our test input to obtain this result, as well as the number of times it can have called `f`. Define now a family of functions

```
g j (B1 : B0 : ... (n+j times) ... B0 : ls)
   = B0 : ... (n+j times) ... B0 : B1 : ls
g j (B0 : ... (n+j times) ... B0 : B1 : ls)
   = B1 : B0 : ... (n+j times) ... B0 : ls
g j l = l
```

Clearly, for all `0<j≤n`, `g j` is a bijection, in fact self-inverse. So we should be able to confirm

```
inv (g j) (replicate (n+j) B0 ++ B1 : repeat B0) -> (B1 : ls)
```

but to fulfill this, `inv (g j)` would have needed to either

- evaluate `g j (B1 : repeat B0)` to a depth of `n+j > n`
- evaluate `head $ g j l` for at least `n` different lists matching `replicate (n+j) B0 ++ B1 : ls`

Up to that point, at least one of the `g j` is indistinguishable from `f`, and since `inv f` hadn't done either of these evaluations, `inv` could not possibly have told it apart – short of doing some runtime-measurements on its own, which is only possible in the `IO Monad`.

⬜

Answer (score 20):

You can look it up on wikipedia, it's called [Reversible Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing).

In general you can't do it though and none of the functional languages have that option. For example:

```
f :: a -> Int
f _ = 1
```

This function does not have an inverse.

Comment: Would it be wrong to say that `f` does have an inverse, it's just that the inverse is a non-deterministic function?

Comment: @MattFenwick In a languages like Haskell for example, functions simply aren't nondeterministic (without changing the types and the way you use them). There does not exist any Haskell function `g :: Int -> a` which is the inverse of `f`, even if you can describe the inverse of `f` mathematically.

Comment: @Matt:  Look up "bottom" in functional programming and logic.  A "bottom" is an "impossible" value, either because it is contradictory, non-terminating, or the solution to an undecidable problem (this is more than merely contradictory -- we can methodically "chase" a solution while we explore a design space using "undefined" and "error" during development).  A "bottom" x has the type a.  It "inhabits" (or is a "value") of every type.  This is a logical contradiction, since types are propositions and there is no value which satisfies every proposition.  Look on Haskell-Cafe for good discussions

Comment: @nomen I fail to understand what your comment has to do with my question. @ benn my question wasn't specific to Haskell.

Comment: @Matt: Rather than characterizing the non-existence of inverses in terms of non-determinism, one must characterize it in terms of bottoms.  The inverse of f _ = 1 is bottom, since it must inhabit every type (alternatively, it is bottom since f has no inverse function for any type with more than a single element -- the aspect you focused on, I think).  Being bottom can be taken both positively and negatively as assertions about values.   One can sensibly speak of the inverse of an arbitrary function as being the "value" bottom. (Even though it's not "really" a value)

Comment: Having wandered back here much later, I think I see what Matt is getting at: we often model nondeterminism via lists, and we could do the same for inverses. Let the inverse of `f x = 2 * x` be `f' x = [x / 2]`, and then the inverse of `f _ = 1` is `f' 1 = [minBound ..]; f' _ = []`. That is, there are many inverses for 1, and none for any other value.

Answer (score 17):

Not in most functional languages, but in logic programming or relational programming, most functions you define are in fact not functions but "relations", and these can be used in both directions. See for example prolog or kanren.

Comment: Or [Mercury](http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/), which otherwise shares a lot of the spirit of Haskell. — Good point, +1.

Answer (score 12):

Tasks like this are almost always undecidable. You can have a solution for some specific functions, but not in general.

Here, you cannot even recognize which functions have an inverse. Quoting [Barendregt, H. P. The Lambda Calculus: Its Syntax and Semantics. North Holland, Amsterdam (1984)](http://mathgate.info/cebrown/notes/barendregt.php):

> A set of lambda-terms is nontrivial if it is neither the empty nor the full set. If A and B are two nontrivial, disjoint sets of lambda-terms closed under (beta) equality, then A and B are recursively inseparable.

Let's take A to be the set of lambda terms that represent invertible functions and B the rest. Both are non-empty and closed under beta equality. So it's not possible to decide whether a function is invertible or not.

(This applies to the untyped lambda calculus. TBH I don't know if the argument can be directly adapted to a typed lambda calculus when we know the type of a function that we want to invert. But I'm pretty sure it will be similar.)

Answer (score 11):

If you can enumerate the domain of the function and can compare elements of the range for equality, you can - in a rather straightforward way. By enumerate I mean having a list of all the elements available. I'll stick to Haskell, since I don't know Ocaml (or even how to capitalise it properly ;-)

What you want to do is run through the elements of the domain and see if they're equal to the element of the range you're trying to invert, and take the first one that works:

```
inv :: Eq b => [a] -> (a -> b) -> (b -> a)
inv domain f b = head [ a | a <- domain, f a == b ]
```

Since you've stated that `f` is a bijection, there's bound to be one and only one such element. The trick, of course, is to ensure that your enumeration of the domain actually reaches all the elements *in a finite time*. If you're trying to invert a bijection from `Integer` to `Integer`, using `[0,1 ..] ++ [-1,-2 ..]` won't work as you'll never get to the negative numbers. Concretely, `inv ([0,1 ..] ++ [-1,-2 ..]) (+1) (-3)` will never yield a value.

However, `0 : concatMap (\x -> [x,-x]) [1..]` will work, as this runs through the integers in the following order `[0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3, and so on]`. Indeed `inv (0 : concatMap (\x -> [x,-x]) [1..]) (+1) (-3)` promptly returns `-4`!

The [Control.Monad.Omega](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/control-monad-omega/0.3/doc/html/Control-Monad-Omega.html) package can help you run through lists of tuples etcetera in a good way; I'm sure there's more packages like that - but I don't know them.

---

Of course, this approach is rather low-brow and brute-force, not to mention ugly and inefficient! So I'll end with a few remarks on the last part of your question, on how to 'write' bijections. The type system of Haskell isn't up to proving that a function is a bijection - you really want something like Agda for that - but it is willing to trust you.

(Warning: untested code follows)

So can you define a datatype of `Bijection` s between types `a` and `b`:

```
data Bi a b = Bi {
    apply :: a -> b,
    invert :: b -> a 
}
```

along with as many constants (where you can say 'I *know* they're bijections!') as you like, such as:

```
notBi :: Bi Bool Bool
notBi = Bi not not

add1Bi :: Bi Integer Integer
add1Bi = Bi (+1) (subtract 1)
```

and a couple of smart combinators, such as:

```
idBi :: Bi a a 
idBi = Bi id id

invertBi :: Bi a b -> Bi b a
invertBi (Bi a i) = (Bi i a)

composeBi :: Bi a b -> Bi b c -> Bi a c
composeBi (Bi a1 i1) (Bi a2 i2) = Bi (a2 . a1) (i1 . i2)

mapBi :: Bi a b -> Bi [a] [b]
mapBi (Bi a i) = Bi (map a) (map i)

bruteForceBi :: Eq b => [a] -> (a -> b) -> Bi a b
bruteForceBi domain f = Bi f (inv domain f)
```

I think you could then do `invert (mapBi add1Bi) [1,5,6]` and get `[0,4,5]`. If you pick your combinators in a smart way, I think the number of times you'll have to write a `Bi` constant by hand could be quite limited.

After all, if you know a function is a bijection, you'll hopefully have a proof-sketch of that fact in your head, which the Curry-Howard isomorphism should be able to turn into a program :-)

Answer (score 6):

I've recently been dealing with issues like this, and no, I'd say that (a) it's not difficult in many case, but (b) it's not efficient at all.

Basically, suppose you have `f :: a -> b`, and that `f` is indeed a bjiection.  You can compute the inverse `f' :: b -> a` in a really dumb way:

```
import Data.List

-- | Class for types whose values are recursively enumerable.
class Enumerable a where
    -- | Produce the list of all values of type @a@.
    enumerate :: [a]

 -- | Note, this is only guaranteed to terminate if @f@ is a bijection!
invert :: (Enumerable a, Eq b) => (a -> b) -> b -> Maybe a
invert f b = find (\a -> f a == b) enumerate
```

If `f` is a bijection and `enumerate` truly produces all values of `a`, then you will eventually hit an `a` such that `f a == b`.

Types that have a `Bounded` and an `Enum` instance can be trivially made `RecursivelyEnumerable`.  Pairs of `Enumerable` types can also be made `Enumerable`:

```
instance (Enumerable a, Enumerable b) => Enumerable (a, b) where
    enumerate = crossWith (,) enumerate enumerate

crossWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
crossWith f _ [] = []
crossWith f [] _ = []
crossWith f (x0:xs) (y0:ys) =
    f x0 y0 : interleave (map (f x0) ys) 
                         (interleave (map (flip f y0) xs)
                                     (crossWith f xs ys))

interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave xs [] = xs
interleave [] ys = []
interleave (x:xs) ys = x : interleave ys xs
```

Same goes for disjunctions of `Enumerable` types:

```
instance (Enumerable a, Enumerable b) => Enumerable (Either a b) where
    enumerate = enumerateEither enumerate enumerate

enumerateEither :: [a] -> [b] -> [Either a b]
enumerateEither [] ys = map Right ys
enumerateEither xs [] = map Left xs
enumerateEither (x:xs) (y:ys) = Left x : Right y : enumerateEither xs ys
```

The fact that we can do this both for `(,)` and `Either` probably means that we can do it for any algebraic data type.

Answer (score 5):

Not every function has an inverse. If you limit the discussion to one-to-one functions, the ability to invert an arbitrary function grants the ability to crack any cryptosystem. We kind of have to hope this isn't feasible, even in theory!

Comment: Any cryptosystem (excluding a few odd ones, like one time pads, which are infeasible for other reasons) can be cracked by brute force. That doesn't make them any less useful, and neither would be an impractically expensive inversion function.

Comment: Does it really? if you think of an encryption function as `String encrypt(String key, String text)` without the key you still won't be able to do anything. EDIT: Plus what delnan said.

Comment: @MaciekAlbin Depends on your attack model. Chosen plaintext attacks, for example, may allow extracting the key, which would then allow attacking other cipher texts encrypted with that key.

Comment: By "feasible" I meant, something that can be done in any reasonable amount of time. I didn't mean "computable" (I'm pretty sure).

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I see your point. But I have to say, I am confused by "feasible in theory" -- doesn't (our definition of) feasibility only refer to how hard it is to do practically?

Comment: OK, well, I'm just a spectator in crypto (as in so much else). But I think the crypto guys would like to show there are functions that are theoretically difficult to invert (trapdoor functions). I.e., it is provably infeasible to invert them. That's what I was trying to express.

Answer (score 5):

In some cases, it is possible to find the inverse of a bijective function by converting it into a symbolic representation. Based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906628/equality-of-functions-in-haskell), I wrote this Haskell program to find inverses of some simple polynomial functions:

```
bijective_function x = x*2+1

main = do
    print $ bijective_function 3
    print $ inverse_function bijective_function (bijective_function 3)

data Expr = X | Const Double |
            Plus Expr Expr | Subtract Expr Expr | Mult Expr Expr | Div Expr Expr |
            Negate Expr | Inverse Expr |
            Exp Expr | Log Expr | Sin Expr | Atanh Expr | Sinh Expr | Acosh Expr | Cosh Expr | Tan Expr | Cos Expr |Asinh Expr|Atan Expr|Acos Expr|Asin Expr|Abs Expr|Signum Expr|Integer
       deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Num Expr where
    (+) = Plus
    (-) = Subtract
    (*) = Mult
    abs = Abs
    signum = Signum
    negate = Negate
    fromInteger a = Const $ fromIntegral a

instance Fractional Expr where
    recip = Inverse
    fromRational a = Const $ realToFrac a
    (/) = Div

instance Floating Expr where
    pi = Const pi
    exp = Exp
    log = Log
    sin = Sin
    atanh = Atanh
    sinh = Sinh
    cosh = Cosh
    acosh = Acosh
    cos = Cos
    tan = Tan
    asin = Asin
    acos = Acos
    atan = Atan
    asinh = Asinh

fromFunction f = f X

toFunction :: Expr -> (Double -> Double)
toFunction X = \x -> x
toFunction (Negate a) = \a -> (negate a)
toFunction (Const a) = const a
toFunction (Plus a b) = \x -> (toFunction a x) + (toFunction b x)
toFunction (Subtract a b) = \x -> (toFunction a x) - (toFunction b x)
toFunction (Mult a b) = \x -> (toFunction a x) * (toFunction b x)
toFunction (Div a b) = \x -> (toFunction a x) / (toFunction b x)


with_function func x = toFunction $ func $ fromFunction x

simplify X = X
simplify (Div (Const a) (Const b)) = Const (a/b)
simplify (Mult (Const a) (Const b)) | a == 0 || b == 0 = 0 | otherwise = Const (a*b)
simplify (Negate (Negate a)) = simplify a
simplify (Subtract a b) = simplify ( Plus (simplify a) (Negate (simplify b)) )
simplify (Div a b) | a == b = Const 1.0 | otherwise = simplify (Div (simplify a) (simplify b))
simplify (Mult a b) = simplify (Mult (simplify a) (simplify b))
simplify (Const a) = Const a
simplify (Plus (Const a) (Const b)) = Const (a+b)
simplify (Plus a (Const b)) = simplify (Plus (Const b) (simplify a))
simplify (Plus (Mult (Const a) X) (Mult (Const b) X)) = (simplify (Mult (Const (a+b)) X))
simplify (Plus (Const a) b) = simplify (Plus (simplify b) (Const a))
simplify (Plus X a) = simplify (Plus (Mult 1 X) (simplify a))
simplify (Plus a X) = simplify (Plus (Mult 1 X) (simplify a))
simplify (Plus a b) = (simplify (Plus (simplify a) (simplify b)))
simplify a = a

inverse X = X
inverse (Const a) = simplify (Const a)
inverse (Mult (Const a) (Const b)) = Const (a * b)
inverse (Mult (Const a) X) = (Div X (Const a))
inverse (Plus X (Const a)) = (Subtract X (Const a))
inverse (Negate x) = Negate (inverse x)
inverse a = inverse (simplify a)

inverse_function x = with_function inverse x
```

This example only works with arithmetic expressions, but it could probably be generalized to work with lists as well. There are also several implementations of [computer algebra systems in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295345/haskell-library-like-sympy) that may be used to find the inverse of a bijective function.

Answer (score 4):

No, not all functions even have inverses. For instance, what would the inverse of this function be?

```
f x = 1
```

Comment: Your function is a constant, here it is about bijective functions.